# How to format number with “ ” as thousand separator, and “,” as decimal separator?

Tags: postgresql

I have a decimal number like `1234567.02`

I would like to make my numbers have space as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator in PostgreSQL.

The expect result is `1 234 567,020`

How can I write such a query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `to_char` to format a number like that.

Set `lc_numeric` appropriately for the decimal separator:

```
SET lc_numeric='de_DE';
```

Since the group separator for that locale is `.`, we use spaces explicitly:

```
SELECT to_char(1234567.02, '9 999 999D999');

    to_char    
---------------
 1 234 567.020
(1 row)
```

Comment: so great! Thanks so much Laurenz Albe